# Understanding the relation between user, kernel and physical addresses in pagedir_get_page()

Tags: c, operating-system, virtual-memory, pintos

I am confused about the following comment:

```
/* Looks up the physical address that corresponds to user virtual
address UADDR in PD.  Returns the kernel virtual address
corresponding to that physical address, or a null pointer if
UADDR is unmapped. */
```

I understand the first sentence which is to find the actual physical address, however, I don't understand why the **kernel** virtual address correspond to that address is returned. In short, since uaddr is a **user** virtual address, then why is it related to **kernel** virtual address?

```
void *
pagedir_get_page (uint32_t *pd, const void *uaddr)
{
  uint32_t *pte;

  ASSERT (is_user_vaddr (uaddr));

  pte = lookup_page (pd, uaddr, false);
  if (pte != NULL && (*pte & PTE_P) != 0)
    return pte_get_page (*pte) + pg_ofs (uaddr);
  else
    return NULL;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does two lookups. First it does <userspace addr> -> <physical addr>, then it does <physical addr> -> <kernel addr>. It gives you a kernel-space address that accesses the same location as a given user-space address.

Comment: A clue is in "or a null pointer if UADDR is unmapped." Physical addresses can't be accessed directly.

Comment: @ThomasJager thanks, then what is this function used for?

Comment: @TonyLucas Presumably to let kernel-level code do something to a given piece of user-space memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three kinds of addresses that the comment is talking about:

1. Physical address: this is the **real** address, I.E. the real exact position in the physical memory of your computer.
2. Kernel *virtual* address: this is the virtual address at which the kernel sees that physical address.
3. User *virtual* address: this is the virtual address at which the user space program sees that physical address.

So, with a simple ASCII art, this is the situation:

```
 User space    
  program 1         Kernel            RAM
+-----------+    +-----------+    +-----------+
| 0xAAAA000 |    | 0x1212000 |    | 0xA7EF000 |
| 0xBBBB000 |    | 0x4398000 |    | 0x0001000 |
| 0xCCCC000 |<---| 0x87FF000 |<---| 0x1234000 |
+-----------+    | ...       |    | ...       |
                 | ...       |    | ...       |
 User space      | ...       |    | ...       |
  program 2      | ...       |    | ...       |
+-----------+    | ...       |    | ...       |
| 0xDDDD000 |    | 0x7FF8000 |    | 0x3FFF000 |
| 0xEEEE000 |    | 0xABCD000 |    | 0x2010000 |
| 0xFFFF000 |<---| 0x98AE000 |<---| 0xA89A000 |
+-----------+    +-----------+    +-----------+
```

That function, given a valid *user space virtual address*, makes a lookup and retrieves the associated *kernel space virtual address*. This lookup can be done since both of them point to the same *physical address*, and there's a one-to-one correspondence between those. The lookup is done through the [Kernel Page Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table), which is probably what those two calls to `lookup_page(...)` and `pte_get_page(...)` do.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think this function is used to **As part of a system call, the kernel must often access memory through pointers provided by a user program. The kernel must be very careful about doing so, because the user can pass a null pointer, a pointer to unmapped virtual memory, or a pointer to kernel virtual address space (above PHYS BASE).**
so I guess, I can use this function to check if this user virtual address is unmapped and if it points to a kernel virtual address(this is not good, because user programs are not able to make changes to kernel memory).

Comment: @TonyLucas yes, that's probably one of the uses. Checking if a user page is valid before touching it is crucial to the correct functioning of the kernel.